# absent alert getting triggered always in prometheus/alertmanager HA setup

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We are switching to regionally sharded prometheus setup and using below AM setup to dedup duplicate alerts: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager#high-availability
The deduping seems to be working fine, but absent alerts are causing issues.

We have one set of metrics, which goes into only one region, and we have some absent alerts setup for those metrics. The data exists only in one region but absent in other remaining regions, which leads to triggering the absent alert based on remaining regions. How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution was to NOT use absent function but instead use other techniques to determine if the metrics are absent.

Some other answers recommended below approach for absent alerts -

`count(cpu_stat offset 1d) by (region) unless count(cpu_stat) by (region)`

The above alert starts firing immediately like absent function but the alert remains active for 1d (for defined offset interval) and gets resolved by itself after that duration. So one need to make sure it is acted in that window. The advantage is that it retains the group by labels unlike absent function.

In our case cpu_stat is not collected at all in some other sharded instances of prometheus. So this alert never fires because there is no occurrence of this metric even 1d before. Hence it solved our problem.

The another thing is -> this is a set operation so even if the cpu_stat count decreases, it will alert. So you can fine tune it based on usual count of the cpu_stats as follows :

```
(count(cpu_stat offset 1d) by (region) unless count(cpu_stat) by (region)) > 40
```

With this, it will alert only when the absent metrics count goes beyond 40 for any region.

Reference -> [prometheus-alert-for-missing-metrics-and-labels](https://niravshah2705.medium.com/prometheus-alert-for-missing-metrics-and-labels-afd4b8f12b1)